# Which model is the best in this case and why?

Tags: model-selection, validation, training-error

I am a newbie in machine learning.
I have a dataset and I have split them into 2 parts include 80% of data for training whereas 20% for testing. 
After training and validation I have some results as follow:
[image]

I have tried to predict with the final models on testing data and the results as follow:
[image]
So, which model is the best in this case and why?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You need the self study tag.

Comment: Random Forest and XGBoost seem to me to be better than CART.  But it is hard to pick between the two. I would look mostly at the test set results.  The 2 models are very close in RMSE and $R^2$. Models are not perfect and there really is no such thing as a best or perfect model.

Comment: Thank you so much. But in case I have to select a model, so which model should I choose?

Comment: I see nothing that is convincing one way or the other.  If you must pick, find some other characteristic that is more convincing.  Random Forest numerically has a slightly higher $R^2$ and lower RMSE on the test data.  So that could be an argument for Random Forests over XGBoost.  But my point is that the difference is so small that the result could easily go the other way on an independent sample of the same size with the same 80% fit and 20% on test set.

Comment: I just add more image to my post for comparing the actual values with predictive modeling. Would you look at there and give me your recommend?

Comment: As I look at the curve it seems that RF is consistently closer to the actual when compared over all the data points. i would go with RF wouldn't you ?

Comment: I see CART is closer to the actual but CART is not a perfect model according to the result tabular.

Comment: I get your point.  I didn't notice the pint dots from CART.  This points to CART and RF looking better than XGBoost.  It just goes to show that all three model predict well.

Comment: Taking a closer look it seems that there are a few outlying predictions that could affect the summary statistics.  For example the actual point just 1 before the furthest point right has both XGBoost and CART far above the actual value where it looks like RF would be much closer to the actual. However I don't see an RF prediction at that point.

Comment: I have zoom out the furthest point and see all 3 points are the same point